# How to implement lazy loading in Angular with dynamic img src

Tags: angularjs, image, lazy-loading, src

I need your help to figure this out: I load several images in my app with dynamic src, so basically I can't predetermine their source, since it depends on certain parameters, like:

```
<img src="assets/images/{{tile.name | sanitiseString}}.jpg">
```

I tried a lot of lazy load plugins but they don't work in this situation.

How can I solve this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is ng-src

This is an example

```
<img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}" alt="Description" />
```

And this is the official documentation [AngularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should work just fine. Just try with tile.name and remove the filter to begin with. Here's an example assuming the "tile" variable is being populated from a http call

```
<img src="{{imgPath}}">

$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1')
   .then(function(response){

     $scope.imgPath = response.data.url;
   })
```

Angularjs keeps re-running the digest cycle to ensure that all the interpolations (within Angular) are assigned values.